# Powershell – Windows startup procedure monitoring

Tags: powershell

I want to conduct some specific actions right after Windows startup (when user is logged on) via PowerShell script. However, I do not want to do it by adding my PowerShell script to Windows Startup because in this way my script will run in the middle of Windows Startup procedure. Therefore, some services and applications may not be started yet. 
I want to run the script when ALL Windows Services are started, all applications from Windows Startup section are run and HDD is not heavily loaded. Is it possible to detect such Windows state using PowerShell?

I would be grateful for any kind of help, because I am running out of ideas…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Powershell startup script. Set it to monitor system [via Perfmon counters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx) and wait untill the system is idle enough. Like so,

```
$epsilon = 0.2
do { # sleep and loop untill cpu load is low enough
    start-sleep -seconds 5
    $counter = Get-Counter "\\computer\Process(Idle)\% Processor Time"
} while ($counter.CounterSamples.CookedValue -ge $epsilon)
# The system is now idle enough
# Start the real work after the loop
```

The proper counter set depends on what you are after. Current disk queue might be of interest too.

The same approach can be used to check service state, running processes and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! Monitoring disk queue is a solution that i needed.